# Can't checkout projects from Github in Android Studio 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

Last night I updated the Android Studio IDE from 3.1.4 to 3.2 stable version, and the weird thing is now I can't checkout projects from Github! May someone tell me how can I do so with the new version of Android Studio?

THANKS in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select `Git` and paste your repository URL. This worked for me (also with a private repository).

Just make sure that your GitHub account is still configured in your preferences. (But since you are updating, I assume it is.)

Answer (score 1):

you can always check out manually by using right click "git bash here" on your workspace->ProjectFolder